# How to get the same text from these 2 contenteditable divs with the same content but different structures?

Tags: javascript, html

Here's the thing:

Contenteditables are bad. **Firefox** handles it with something like the `div1` and **Chrome** does it like `div2`.

Both have the same text content (as from the user's perspective), but they're structured in different ways.

When I get both text contents with `innerText`, I get back different results, because of the way they're structured.

Is there a way to get those texts and get back the same string (since they produce the exact same text on screen)?

Something like:

`div1 = div2 = "Line1\nLine2\n\nLine3\n\n\nLine4"` (in fact, that's the `div1` result, since it's composed only by text and breaks). `div2` is the problem, in this case.

**The pseudo code of what I need:**

"Get my the text content of these `div` with the number of breaks based on what is being shown on the screen."

**Final goal:**

To paste new text consistently across both structures I need a way to handle them in the same way.

```js
const div1 = document.getElementById('div1');
const div2 = document.getElementById('div2');
const p1 = document.getElementById('p1');
const p2 = document.getElementById('p2');

p1.innerText = JSON.stringify(div1.innerText);
p2.innerText = JSON.stringify(div2.innerText);
```

```css
#div1 {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

#div2 {
  margin-top: 40px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1" contenteditable>
  Line1
  <br>
  Line2
  <br>
  <br>
  Line3
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  Line4
</div>

<p><b>Div1 innerText:</b></p>
<p id="p1"></p>

<div id="div2" contenteditable>
  <div>Line1</div>
  <div>Line2</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>Line3</div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div><br></div>
  <div>Line4</div>
</div>

<p><b>Div2 innerText:</b></p>
<p id="p2"></p>
```

Comment: Any closing `</div>` will add a `\n` as well as any `<br>`

Comment: Why don't you use a `<textarea>` instead of `contenteditable`?

Comment: @iArcadia I need to style some parts of the content in a "tagged user mention" system.

Comment: Still possible. You could convert your `<div>`'s content into a `<textarea>` on click, then reverse it when clicking outside. Just an idea.

Comment: @iArcadia how can I convert a `div`'s content into a `textarea`? Would the `div` be `contenteditable`? Would you have some example code of that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggested you in comments to transform your `<div>`'s content into a `<textarea>` element. This solution avoids behavior difference between Firefox and Chrome.

Here is below a simple example about how it can be achieved. I guess you will be able to adapt it with what you want exactly (switching `<p>` to `<div>` for instance).

```js
const contentEditable = document.querySelector('#content-editable'),
  htmlPreview = document.querySelector('#html-preview');

htmlPreview.innerText = contentEditable.innerHTML;

contentEditable.addEventListener('click', contentEditableHtmlToTextarea);

/**
 * Converts HTML of #content-editable into <textarea>.
 */
function contentEditableHtmlToTextarea() {
  const textarea = document.createElement('textarea'),
    height = contentEditable.offsetHeight;
  
  // Converts <p> tags to \r\n.
  textarea.value = this.innerHTML
    .replace(/^\s*/gm, '')
    .replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, '$1\r\n')
    .trim();
    
  // Updates #content-editable HTML.
  this.innerHTML = '';
  this.appendChild(textarea);
  
  textarea.style.height = `${height}px`;
  htmlPreview.style.display = 'none';
  
  this.removeEventListener('click', contentEditableHtmlToTextarea);
  
  // A bit tricky, but without timeout, the callback is directly called.
  setTimeout(() => {
    document.addEventListener('click', contentEditableTextareaToHtml);
  }, 0);
}

/**
 * Converts <textarea>'s value into HTML for #content-editable.
 */
function contentEditableTextareaToHtml(e) {
  const textarea = contentEditable.querySelector('textarea'),
    // Converts lines into <p> tags.
    html = textarea.value.replace(/^(.+?)$/gm, '<p>$1</p>');
    
  // Checks if the mouse click is outside the <textarea>.
  if (e.target !== textarea) {
    // Updates #content-editable HTML.
    textarea.remove();
    contentEditable.innerHTML = html;
    htmlPreview.innerText = contentEditable.innerHTML;
    
    htmlPreview.style.display = 'block';
    
    document.removeEventListener('click', contentEditableTextareaToHtml);
    contentEditable.addEventListener('click', contentEditableHtmlToTextarea);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 3px;
  
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

textarea {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;

  width: 98%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-editable">
  <p>Line 1</p>
  <p>Line 2</p>
  <p>Line 3</p>
</div>

<pre id="html-preview"></pre>
```